# Как сделать отметки на фото?

Tags: flash, javascript, php

На сайте нужно реализовать отметку на фотографии. По типу как в ВКонтакте. Желательно, но необязательно, чтобы выделение объекта было не в прямоугольник, а в полигон. Есть готовые реализации? Не важно какую технологию использовать php, flash и прочие, но экзотику не надо :)

Comment: Так и в чём вопрос? Делайте обычным ява-скриптом.. это ведь совсем несложно..  начать и кончить, что называется..

Comment: Не, ну понятно же, в чём вопрос. Человек хочет готовую реализацию (ну лично я считаю, что готовая реализация в абсолютном большинстве случаем на порядок лучше чем самодеятельность).

Comment: Все верно, меня интересует готовая реализация. Дело в том что такую штуку нужно применить лишь несколько раз и в удобоваримом виде представить на сайте. Разумно взять что-нибудь готовое. На "написать с нуля" понадобится довольно много времени.

Comment: Попробую переформулировать задачу :)
Нужно отметить нужные объекты на чертеже. 
В результате должен быть выведен чертеж, когда мы подводим на объект получаем подсказку под чертежом или сразу под указателем мыши. Лаконичнее отмечать полигонами, но сгодится и прямоугольникам, ведь его можно разбить на несколько прямоугольников.
Задача элементарная вроде бы. Наверняка есть решения, так сказать wysiwyg :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Если кому пригодится, то существует хороший редактор: [iMapBuilder Interactive Flash Map Builder](http://www.imapbuilder.com/).

Answer (score 4):

С полигонами сложнее, а вот прямоугольник элементарно:
[jQuery UI → draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) + [jQuery UI → resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/).

Answer (score 2):

Для клиентской части можно попробовать [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) для jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [`jquery.photolabel()`](http://readyscript.ru/photolabel/) - это плагин, позволяющий отмечать людей и выводить отметки на фото, подобно тому, как это сделано ВКонтакте.

Answer (score -1):

На простом javascript это делается проще всего на прототипах:

```
var p = function() {}
p.prototype = {
    state: 0,
    __construct: function() {},
    create: function() {
        // тут создаем div 100x100
        // вешаем на него обработчики this.mmove, this.mup, this.mdown
    },
    mmove: function() {
        if (this.state == 1) {
            // перемещаем элемент
        }
    },
    mdown: function() {
        this.state = 1;
    },
    mup: function() {
        this.state = 0;
    }
}
var photo = new p();
```

Это по поводу перемещения div, по поводу ресайза все аналогично.

А готовую реализацию Вы можете взять из вконтакте :)

Comment: Думаю, вопрос был не «Какой есть самый хитрый в мире способ навесить хэндлеры событий на объект?». Суть вопроса в том, что надо бы где-то взять хороший код перетаскивания и изменения размера (типа как тут был вопрос про то, что надо, чтобы перетаскивания заканчивалось, когда кнопку отпускают за рамкой окна и всё такое).